# How to submit form data in the same page in WordPress without reloading the page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom PHP template - form. I'm trying to send this form in the same page using AJAX without reloading the page. Hide the form after submission and display the `thank you` message. This form is displayed in a modal. But what happens is that the page is still reloading.

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="" name="modalForm" id="modalForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
        <input placeholder="Last Name*" type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value="" required>
        <label class="error" for="name" id="lastName_error">This field is required.</label>
        <input placeholder="First Name*" type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="" required>
        <label class="error" for="name" id="firstName_error">This field is required.</label>
        <input placeholder="Email Address" type="email" name="Email" id="Email" onblur="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="" required>
        <label class="error" for="email" id="email_error">This field is required.</label>
        <span class="validation-text">Please enter a valid email address.</span>
        <input placeholder="Mobile Number*" type="text" name="contactNumber" id="contactNumber" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" value="" size="11" minlength="11" maxlength="11" pattern ="^09\d{9}$" required>
        <label class="error" for="contactNumber" id="contactNumber_error">This field is required.</label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="form-submit">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
    (function($) {
    $('.error').hide();
    $(".button").click(function() {
      // validate and process form here

      $('.error').hide();
        var name = $("input#lastName").val();
        if (lastName == "") {
        $("label#lastName_error").show();
        $("input#lastName").focus();
        return false;
      }
        var name = $("input#firstName").val();
        if (lastName == "") {
        $("label#firstName_error").show();
        $("input#firstName").focus();
        return false;
      }
        var email = $("input#Email").val();
        if (Email == "") {
        $("label#email_error").show();
        $("input#Email").focus();
        return false;
      }
        var phone = $("input#contactNumber").val();
        if (contactNumber == "") {
        $("label#contactNumber_error").show();
        $("input#contactNumber").focus();
        return false;
      }

    });

    var dataString = 'lastName='+ lastName + '&Email=' + Email + '&contactNumber=' + contactNumber;
  //alert (dataString);return false;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/wordpress-page/",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
      $('#modalForm').html("<div id='message'></div>");
      $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
      .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
      .hide()
      .fadeIn(1500, function() {
        $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
      });
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Move the closing bracket (line 32) of the click-event to the bottom (after line 51), and you should be fine.

Comment: You might want to look into using the built in WP AJAX to handle your requests so you can hook into the call instead of needing to have a page receive the data https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

Comment: @SpazzMarticus, after form submit, the page is still reloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a fiddle with [your code](https://jsfiddle.net/h3afnzd2/) and with the [fixed code](https://jsfiddle.net/8mrcrzk7/).

1. The whole code runs as soon as possible, but should run after the DOM is ready, so that the selectors can match DOM-elements: `(function($) {` should be changed to `($(document).ready(function(){`
2. Your selector `$('.button')` does not match any elements, in your case it should match the submit-button `$('#form-submit')`
3. I would add `preventDefault()` to make sure the default action of the submit button (submitting the form) won't happen.
4. The form validation is really messed up. You are checking a variables that are not set.
5. Your `dataString` also uses unset variables. (First name is also missing.)

I exchanged the ajax call for a `console.log` to dump the data, but kept the success-function.

---

There are so many small errors in your code, that it looks like you copied it from different sources without doing much debugging before asking this question.

Try debugging step by step as you write your code.

Comment: I tried to apply the fixed code that you gave, but still the wordpress page is reloading after form submitted

Comment: The fiddle works, are your javascript files included correctly? Debug with log-messages like these: https://jsfiddle.net/ftemjLvu/

Comment: yes, that's I wonder why the ajax not working in my wordpress page

Comment: can you pls help me with this one, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/292485/wordpress-ajaxifying-not-working-properly, it's a continuation of Ajaxifying